# DB4o 8.0 java 1.6 juno - import database to project

Tags: java, db4o

I would like to add to my project db4o 8.0. I installed db4o and I'm using JUNO eclipse but I don't know where I have to find direction of installed file to add items to file for example:

> import db4o.Db4oEmbedded
>
> import db4o.ObjectContainer
>
> import db4o.config.EmbeddedConfiguartion

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer there is JAR in eclipse file. If will be not added to project db4o will not working.

> C:\Users\Rafal\Desktop\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\859\1.cp